# How to override comment render function?

Tags: 7

I am new to Drupal, I just want to change "**SELECT**" query of **comment table** without changing any core file functionality

I am doing this in my `template.php`.

```
$variables['commentsResult'] = db_query("SELECT c.*,fm.* FROM comment
as c LEFT JOIN file_managed fm ON c.fid = fm.fid WHERE c.nid   ='".$node_id."'");
```

Now I want "**comments Result**" variable on `comment-wrapper--node-forum.tpl.php` in theme